# How do I make this one document in printing (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, printing

Currently, I have a few numbers that need to be printed on an otherwise blank page. So I put my calculations in a loop and print in a one-page multi-file system, but it doesn't look pretty (thousands of files in printer queue). The code is something like this:

```
                    printDialog1.ShowDialog();

                        calc();
                        int z = 0;

                        while (z != bp)
                        {
                            printDocument1.Print();
                            z++;
                        }
```

I can't figure out how to, instead of print immediately, add this as a new page to the document.

Comment: [PrintDocument.PrintPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=netframework-4.8) I think You are missing part with checking if document have more pages (this parts should be in You loop) and after that call to print

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PrintPageEventArgs to define if there are more pages something like this :

```
    void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int z = 0;
        while (z != bp)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            z++;
        }
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```